# Customize newline-and-indent function

Tags: indentation, newlines

I'd like to extends this function to work as usual in most cases but if current line starts with `*` then it should indent and then insert `*`. Particularly i want to use it in multi line comments, i.e:

```
/**
  * multiline comment
  */
```

So when i press `Ret`, while writing a comment, it would add `*`.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but if you just write one long line and then hit M-q the comment will be broken into several lines in the appropriate way.

Answer (score 3):

I think the command you want to use is `comment-indent-new-line` which is normally bound to `M-j`.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't insert `*`, is there any way to fix this?

Comment: It does when I test it with `emacs -Q ~/tmp/foo.c` and type `/** RET * foo M-j` so you'll need to give more details about your setup to figure out why it doesn't work for you.

Comment: Probably i should, it works for `C`, but i'm interested in [scala-mode2](https://github.com/hvesalai/scala-mode2)

Comment: Then you should report the problem to the scala-mode2 maintainers.